# get pdf point(x, y coordinates) of selected text or pdfelement from pdfjs

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I have used pdf.js to view a pdf in a web-browser. Also, window.getSelection() to get the selected text. However, I want to get the pdf point or x, y coordinates of the selection, so that I can save them coordinates and use it to scan similar pdfs and extract text.

How can I do that?

Comment: Visit this link I think it's answer to your question [pdf.js with window.selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950038/how-do-i-retrieve-text-from-user-selection-in-pdf-js?answertab=active#tab-top)