# How to extract content of PDF in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf-parsing

I am trying to load PDF file of my local storage then extract content in React.js without any backend.

I tried to find similar modules from google, but didn't find proper module yet.
There are many node modules for parsing PDFs, and I can extract content of PDF in backend, but I am not sure we can use it in web browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49763744/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks JASBIR, But I need to load PDF of my local driver in React.js.
In this case I can get PDF using input DOM. And then I don't know how I can do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this, and `pdfjs-dist` was no longer functional. Instead, a better alternative to extract text from a PDF directly within React was `react-pdftotext`.

**1. Install the library:**

```
npm install react-pdftotext
```

**2. Import the library:**

```
import pdfToText from 'react-pdftotext'
```

**3. Create an input field:**

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" onChange={extractText}/>
```

**4. Prepare a function:**

```
    function extractText(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        pdfToText(file)
            .then(text => console.log(text))
            .catch(error => console.error("Failed to extract text from pdf"))
    }
```

**Finally, bringing it all together:**

```
import pdfToText from 'react-pdftotext'


function extractText(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    pdfToText(file)
        .then(text => console.log(text))
        .catch(error => console.error("Failed to extract text from pdf"))
}

function PDFParserReact() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <input type="file" accept="application/pdf" onChange={extractText}/>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
export default PDFParserReact;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a react application then you can use "[react-pdftotext](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdftotext)" package to extract text from pdfs on browsers. For detail on how to use this package you can refer to this [article](https://dev.to/utkarsh212/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-pdf-in-react-2afl).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).